# Is there an identity function in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is there an identity function already defined Elixir ?

Something like:

`identity = fn a -> a end`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Function.identity/1` has been added to Elixir v1.10.0-dev recently:

[Commit](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/ebf31180f7b650049999239c5eec48d46ba304fc)

Usage example:

```
Enum.map([1, 2, 3, 4], &Function.identity/1)
```

Answer (score 39):

@focused is correct - 1.10-dev has added the identity function.

[Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/Function.html#identity/1)

Old Answer:
No such function has been predefined (at least that I'm aware of). It can trivially be written as you've done in your question, or more succinctly as `&(&1)`.